Working on a Blazor app, my buttons aren't calling my methods
I'm working on a Blazor project for some personal learning, and I've hit an issue that I can't seem to figure out the solution to. That being most of my browser-side buttons don't seem to do anything, likely because they aren't calling my methods. I've checked my syntax, debugged my code, and checked for errors on browser side and I can't see anything that should be wrong. Everything I can find elsewhere says there shouldn't be a problem with my code, so I'm here to ask for help. Below is the razor page, 'cause I can't imagine that the problem is with my CS partial page.
Here's my razor page
        `@page "/deckedit"
        @page "/deckedit/{DeckId}"

        @using DeckBuilder.Shared

        @if (!Saved)
        {
            <section class="deck-edit">
                <h1 class="page-title">@Deck.DeckName</h1>
                <EditForm Model="@Deck" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit"             OnInvalidSubmit="@HandleInvalidSubmit" FormName="DeckEdit">
                    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="deckname" class="col-sm-3">Deck Name: </label>
                        <InputText id="deckname" class="form-control col-sm-8" @bind-            Value="@Deck.DeckName" placeholder="Enter deck name"></InputText>
                        <ValidationMessage class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-8" For="@(() =>             Deck.DeckName)"     />
                    </div>
  
                    @if (Deck.DeckId != 0)
                    {
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (string card in Cards)
                            {
                                <li>
                                   <li>@card</li>
                                    <button type="button" @onclick="() =>             RemoveCard(card)">Remove Card</button>
                                </li>
                             }
                        </ul>
                    
                    }
       
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" @bind="newCard" placeholder="Enter New Card"     />
                        <button type="button" @onclick="AddCard">Add Card</button>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary edit-btn">Save         Deck</button>

                    @if (Deck.DeckId > 0)
                    {
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@DeleteDeck">Delete Deck</a>
                    }


                </EditForm>
            </section>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="alert @StatusClass">@Message</div>
        }`


I suspect the rendermode used for rendering your page. Seems SSR is used, for interactivity you need an interactive rendermode.

Please provide these two pieces of information: Your Routes component and how it is used in probably the App.razor component.

Here is my Routes






And here is the app.razor

















@TacoTown - look at how this looks. Use [edit] to improve a question.

You have chosen the wrong options when you set up your project.  You're page is being rendered statically.
See this answer
What does 'interactivity location' mean when creating a Blazor App from a template?
And review the information in this MS Documents article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Ok? That explains why but neither of those links really explain how to fix it. I tried adding the @rendermode="InteractiveServer" mentioned in the first one to my App.razor, and the .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode() and .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents() to my Program.cs file, but I just get errors about how the definitions don't exist, and F12ing into them doesn't give me any more answers either.

@TacoTown - the easiest path is to start over. Otherwise, create a scratch project and compare (copy) Program.cs, App.razor and Routes.razor

So make another project and choose global instead of per page/component?

Yes, or set the Render mode in App.razor.
